# How to get parameter values from an XmlNode in C#

Tags: c#, xml

How do I get the values for parameters in a XmlNode tag.  For example:

```
<weather time-layout="k-p24h-n7-1">
    <name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>
    <weather-conditions weather-summary="Mostly Sunny"/>
</weather>
```

I want to get the value for the parameter 'weather-summary' in the node 'weather-conditions'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var node = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("weather/weather-conditions");
var attr = node.Attributes["weather-summary"];
```

Answer (score 4):

In the interest of completeness, the .Net 3.5 way should be given as well:

Assuming

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<weather time-layout='k-p24h-n7-1'>
    <name>Weather Type, Coverage, and Intensity</name>
    <weather-conditions weather-summary='Mostly Sunny'/></weather>");
```

Then either

```
return doc.Element("weather").Element("weather-conditions").Attribute("weather-summary").Value;
```

Or

```
return doc.Descendants("weather-conditions").First().Attribute("weather-summary").Value;
```

Will give you the same answer.